# Optimal way to flatten long dataframe with or without pivot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, pivot-table

I have a long dataframe to flatten.
The dataframe looks like this. I want to flatten this table, use `referenceDate` `companyId` as index, the columns should have two layers, the first one is `data_item` and the second would be `N`. I know pd.pivot would solve the problem.

```
+---------------+-----------+-----------+---+-------+
| referenceDate | CompanyId | data_item | N | value |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+---+-------+
| 2020-01-31    |         1 | A         | 1 | 0.1   |
| 2020-01-31    |         2 | A         | 2 | 0.2   |
| 2020-01-31    |         3 | A         | 3 | 0.3   |
+---------------+-----------+-----------+---+-------+
```

However,

```
df = pd.pivot(df, values='value', index=['referenceDate', 'companyId'], columns=['data_item', 'N'])
```

always gives valueError

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\venvs\\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3343, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-56-3738f20d42ed>", line 1, in <module>
    df = pd.pivot(df, values='value', index=['referenceDate', 'companyId'], columns=['data_item', 'N'])
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\venvs\\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py", line 429, in pivot
    indexed = data._constructor_sliced(data[values].values, index=index)
  File "C:\Users\\PycharmProjects\venvs\\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 302, in __init__
    "index implies {ind}".format(val=len(data), ind=len(index))
ValueError: Length of passed values is 239689, index implies 2
```

`pd.pivot_table` works well, but I don't need aggregation in this case, and I also have concern on the performance when the dataframe is of large size (in billions rows). Actually I do have a Memory Error here, it says can't allocate 1.xxGB for a numpy array when I executed this:

```
df = pd.pivot_table(df, values='value', index=['referenceDate', 'companyId'],
                                            columns=['data_item', 'N'], aggfunc='first')
```

I was wondering why `pd.pivot` fails here and beside `pd.pivot` and `pd.pivot_table`, if there is an optimal solution (require least memory) to my problem?

Comment: What version of pandas are you on? You can check with `pd.__version__`

Comment: @DavidErickson 0.25.3, that's was from this project's requirements.txt. Would that be a problem?

Comment: see my answer. I'm pretty sure it has to do with having an older pandas version where `pivot` had bugs.

Comment: please accept one of the answers as solution by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to upgrade to a newer version of pandas if you can temporarily or permanently as `pivot` has bugs in earlier versions of pandas.

For example, you can do this: `pip install pandas==1.1.3` to upgrade to a specific version where they fixed `pivot`.

```
pip install pandas==1.1.3
# then restart the kernel

import pandas as pd
# df = ....
df = pd.pivot(df, values='value', index=['referenceDate', 'CompanyId'], columns=['data_item', 'N'])
df
Out[1]: 
data_item                  A          
N                          1    2    3
referenceDate CompanyId               
2020-01-31    1          0.1  NaN  NaN
              2          NaN  0.2  NaN
              3          NaN  NaN  0.3
```

Then, you can always go back with `pip install pandas==0.25.3`. You can do this all from your jupyter notebbok. Make sure to restart the kernel each time you switch versions.

My current version of pandas is `1.0.1`, so I also receive the same error!

```
pip install pandas==1.0.1
#restart kernel

import pandas as pd
#df = ...
df = pd.pivot(df, values='value', index=['referenceDate', 'CompanyId'], columns=['data_item', 'N'])
df
```

Error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-11248dbe0eba> in <module>
      1 df = d.copy()
----> 2 df = pd.pivot(df, values='value', index=['referenceDate', 'CompanyId'], columns=['data_item', 'N'])
      3 df

C:\Users\david.erickson\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\reshape\pivot.py in pivot(data, index, columns, values)
    445             )
    446         else:
--> 447             indexed = data._constructor_sliced(data[values].values, index=index)
    448     return indexed.unstack(columns)
    449 

C:\Users\david.erickson\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in __init__(self, data, index, dtype, name, copy, fastpath)
    290                     if len(index) != len(data):
    291                         raise ValueError(
--> 292                             f"Length of passed values is {len(data)}, "
    293                             f"index implies {len(index)}."
    294                         )

ValueError: Length of passed values is 3, index implies 2.
```